# How to retrieve value from form_dropdown() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.I have simple form_dropdown(). I want to execute an onchange() function  for my drop down.

I will get the string which was selected through JavaScript.

This is my code but its not working

```
$js ="onChange=message()";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" > function message(){ var no=document.getElementById('name').value;

alert(sr);
}
</script>";
echo form_dropdown('name',$data,'large',$js);
```

Comment: This is calling its onchange funtion which we have to pass in form_dropdown() as forth parameter.

Comment: What is the javascript error from the console?

Comment: i am sorry i don't how to get console for javascript in browser.Right now i am using google chrome..

Comment: @user1594794 then add one from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firebug-lite-for-google-c/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench?hl=en

Comment: @sandip message() is a javascript function which is written there after "<script type=\"text/javascript\" > this..

Comment: What is the javascript error from the console?

Comment: "uncaught type error cannot read property of value null"  javascript console error

Comment: @user1594794 u are doing alert sr where you have defined this variable ?

Comment: oopsss..now i have change sr variable with no variable which i am using  .But still give me error "[Exception]type error: cannot read property value of null"

Answer (score 0):

form_dropdown doesn't automatically add an id to the element, so `getElementById` won't work as written.

also, for understanding's sake, the guide doesn't do a good job of explaining the fourth parameter. Calling it `$js` is misleading, as it well add anything you give it to the attributes list.

Change the one line of code to this (note the quotes around the onChange function as well):

```
 $js = 'id = "name" onChange="message();"';
```

make sure you're viewing your source code after it's output to verify it is outputting valid html as well.

Also, on Chrome, F12 will bring up your developer tools, and hitting the esc key will toggle showing your JavaScript console, which will hopefully give you meaningful errors if everything doesn't go as planned.

Edit:

It also looks like you're setting the value of a variable called `no`, but alerting a variable called `sr`, which doesn't seem to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

you can also simply pass ref from function call that would easy instead of getting value from `document.getElementById()`, it will work when you will add id in select dropdowm

try this code

```
<?php 
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" > 
        function message(element){ 
           var no=element.value;
           alert(no);
         }
</script>";

echo form_dropdown('name',$data,'large', 'onChange="message(this);"'); 

?>
```